# Hover a background image to reveal a social media icon

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple background images that, when hovered, need to reveal a [Pinterest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinterest) icon with a hyperlink. Using the code below, I am able to bring in the Pinterest logo, on hover, with CSS. However, I have two issues. The first, is I seem unable to get the social media icon to transition in slowly, so it's not so abrupt.

My second problem is that I have a CSS hover state on the background image to fade to 50% opacity. However, when you hover the Social media icon, the background image loses its fade, as it is no longer being hovered on. I think this is a JavaScript solution, but have been unable to resolve the issues.

```css
.fading-image:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.pinterest-appear {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    transition: opacity 750ms ease-in-out 200ms;
    opacity: 0;
}

.fading-image-container:hover .pinterest-appear {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="fading-image-container">
  <img class= "fading-image" src="http://box5385.temp.domains/~atelifw5/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/RO_PIX_EV_01_1320px.jpg">
  <a class="pinterest-appear" href="https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" target="blank">
    <img src="http://box5385.temp.domains/~atelifw5/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Pinterest_Black.svg">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solutions to both issues above. I simply edited my CSS on the class "pinterest-appear" setting the display property to "block". I then added another CSS target, as below.

```
.fading-image-container:hover .fading-image {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: You could make your answer better if you extend how you found the solution. If by found you mean that you got the idea somewhere it's fair to give appropriate attribution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing. If this was by doing trial and error and you learned something that help you to find helpful references, you could also add this. Think on this site as knowledge base that aspires to be helpful to future readers.

Comment: Thank you Ruben. I was able to come to the solution by continuing to fiddle with the code.